# Regex occurrence help in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a specific use case to identify the sentences that end with colon (`:`) and start with a full stop (`.`)

I have another condition that if the full stop is followed by a number then it should look for previous full stop.

Here is an example

Input statement:
`but I have been in a loop. two and fro: he has been facing some issues. I am more of a morning person (10 to 9.30):`

here is the regex which I am currently using in python:
`[\w\s\(\)(\,\-]+(?<!\d)(?<![0-9]\)):(?<!\d)(?<![0-9]\))|(\w)+\s(\w)+\s(?<!\d)(?<![0-9]\)):|(?<!\d)(\w)+\s(((\w)\s)*(\w))\s(?<!\d)(?<![0-9]\)):`

This only matches `two and fro:`
I want to match 2 statements that are:

1. two and fro:
2. I am more of a morning person (10 to 9.30):

The way I am looking at the problem statement is that I start with finding a colon and then traverse back till I find a full stop and then check if that full stop is followed by a number. If yes then I need to traverse even back further to find another full stop that is not followed by a number.

Comment: No **use case** ever said *"use negative look behind"*. Are you sure you are not presenting an x y problem?

Comment: Updated the Question @Klaus D.

Comment: So after the full stop ("."), there must be a space (" ") I assumed? Because normal way to start a new sentence is a dot followed by a space.

Comment: we need to take that into consideration that there will be a space. even if it is not there then also it should work. @HoangMinhQuangFX15045

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)
The pattern uses a positive lookbehind `(?<=\. )` to match any character that is preceded by a period and a space
`\w.*?:` matches `any word character` followed by `any characters` zero or more times until the colon is found.

```py
import re

string = "but I have been in a loop. two and fro: he has been facing some issues. I am more of a morning person (10 to 9.30):"

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\. )\w.*?:')
target = re.findall(pattern, string)
print(target)
```

---

```
['two and fro:', 'I am more of a morning person (10 to 9.30):']
```

You can also use `split()` to get the same output:

```py
data = string.split(". ")
target = [f'{i.split(":")[0]}:' for i in data if ":" in i]
print(target)
```

Comment: so the way i am looking at the problem statement is that I start with finding a colon and then traverse back till i find a full stop and then check if that full stop is followed by a number. If yes then i need to traverse even back further to find another full stop that is not followed by a number

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
(?<=\. ).*?:
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/56136J/1)

It will match anything behind a `.` followed by a space   and end with a colon `:`

- `(?<=\. )` positive lookbehind `(?<=)` a dot `\.` and a space
- `.*?` match anything `.` non greedy `*?` (as few as possible)
- `:` end with a colon

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple regex which does what you are asking.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '''but I have been in a loop. two and fro: he has been facing some issues. I am more of a morning person (10 to 9.30):'''
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\.(?=\D)\s*)[^:]*:', text)
['. two and fro:', '. I am more of a morning person (10 to 9.30):']
```

The lookahead `\.(?=\D)` says the full stop must immediately be followed by a non-number.

If you want to omit the full stop from the previous sentence you can turn that into a lookbehind.

```
(?<=\.(?=\D))[^:]*:
```

That will still leave whitespace at the start. Python `re` does not allow you to add a variable-width expression like `\s*` to the lookbehind, but the third-party `regex` library will permit that.

```
import regex
regex.findall(r'(?<=\.(?=\D)\s*)[^:]*:', text)
```

Perhaps you would actually also like to match a sentence at the very beginning of the text?

```
>>> regex.findall(r'(?<=\A|\.(?=\D)\s*)[^\s:.](?:[^:.]|\.\d)*:', 'help: ' + text)
['help:', 'two and fro:', 'I am more of a morning person (10 to 9.30):']
```

This is refactored to be more picky about what it allows in the actual match.